# Complex Absolute Value as Real Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The following identity appears in Noam Elkies‘ answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167685/absolute-value-inequality-for-complex-numbers/167747#167747) to a certain inequality problem:

$$
|z| = \frac14 \int_0^{2\pi} \bigl| {\rm Re}(e^{i\theta} z) \bigr| \, d\theta.
$$
I haven’t seen this anywhere before, and can’t see why it’s true. Is there a quick proof of this? I’d also appreciate more instances of this idea of averaging over projections.

Comment: Note that the equality is invariant under rotation by $|\alpha|=1$ as well as under multiplication with $r>0$ so  it is enough to consider $z=0$ and $z=1$ for which the equalities are immediate

Comment: This is to me a much better way to see the identity, and I would have accepted it if it were an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

- $z=|z|e^{i\phi}$
- $\Re(e^{i\alpha})=\cos\alpha$
- write explicitly where the cosine function is positive